# tcl: wish and wish <source> difference

Tags: tcl

I am new to Tcl/tk, confused by the way "wish" find commands.

I can run other program the same way in a terminal from wish when runs interactively(given a command, wish will run a executable from PATH directories from ENV), but when run like `wish <source>`, call other executables got cmd not found error, and I must use `[exec "<executable_name>"]` to do that, I have read the documents on www.tcl.tk, only find out that when run like `wish <source>`, no .wishrc loaded automatically(I have checked there is no such file on my disk).

Any one know why can not call executable in PATH directly from script source files?

Answer (score 2):

If Tcl can't find a command, [it executes `unknown`] (with the original command as arguments) and uses the result from that as the result of the missing command.

If Tcl runs in interactive mode (`tcl_interactive` is 1, the command is executed on level 0 and there is no current script execution) it will try a few further steps to find something that might be executed:

```
if {([info level] == 1) && ([info script] eq "")  && [info exists tcl_interactive] && $tcl_interactive} {
    if {![info exists auto_noexec]} {
        set new [auto_execok $name]
        if {$new ne ""} {
            set redir ""
            if {[namespace which -command console] eq ""} {
                set redir ">&@stdout <@stdin"
            }
            uplevel 1 [list ::catch  [concat exec $redir $new [lrange $args 1 end]]  ::tcl::UnknownResult ::tcl::UnknownOptions]
            dict incr ::tcl::UnknownOptions -level
            return -options $::tcl::UnknownOptions $::tcl::UnknownResult
        }
    }
    if {$name eq "!!"} {
        set newcmd [history event]
    } elseif {[regexp {^!(.+)$} $name -> event]} {
        set newcmd [history event $event]
    } elseif {[regexp {^\^([^^]*)\^([^^]*)\^?$} $name -> old new]} {
        set newcmd [history event -1]
        catch {regsub -all -- $old $newcmd $new newcmd}
    }
    if {[info exists newcmd]} {
        tclLog $newcmd
        history change $newcmd 0
        uplevel 1 [list ::catch $newcmd  ::tcl::UnknownResult ::tcl::UnknownOptions]
        dict incr ::tcl::UnknownOptions -level
        return -options $::tcl::UnknownOptions $::tcl::UnknownResult
    }

    set ret [catch {set candidates [info commands $name*]} msg]
    if {$name eq "::"} {
        set name ""
    }
    if {$ret != 0} {
        dict append opts -errorinfo  "\n    (expanding command prefix \"$name\" in unknown)"
        return -options $opts $msg
    }
    # Filter out bogus matches when $name contained
    # a glob-special char [Bug 946952]
    if {$name eq ""} {
        # Handle empty $name separately due to strangeness
        # in [string first] (See RFE 1243354)
        set cmds $candidates
    } else {
        set cmds [list]
        foreach x $candidates {
            if {[string first $name $x] == 0} {
                lappend cmds $x
            }
        }
    }
    if {[llength $cmds] == 1} {
        uplevel 1 [list ::catch [lreplace $args 0 0 [lindex $cmds 0]]  ::tcl::UnknownResult ::tcl::UnknownOptions]
        dict incr ::tcl::UnknownOptions -level
        return -options $::tcl::UnknownOptions $::tcl::UnknownResult
    }
    if {[llength $cmds]} {
        return -code error "ambiguous command name \"$name\": [lsort $cmds]"
    }
}
```

First it checks if there is any command with that name that can be executed.
Then it checks if there is any history substitution.
And finally, it checks if there is an unique prefix of this command.

Comment: The other thing to note is that it is considered bad form to rely on `unknown` to handle things when running non-interactively if it doesn't need to. `unknown` is not a particularly fast mechanism, as it is considered to be a failure-recovery mechanism at heart…

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add path into /usr/bin/wish script.

## file /usr/bin/wish

/usr/bin/wish: POSIX shell script text executable